# Netinfo.isConnected always returns true in Android

Tags: android, react-native

i am using [react-native-netinfo](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo) in my app. In iOS it's working fine. But in android always returns true. It doesn't have internet connection (WiFi or Mobile data). It still returns true. Please give me any suggestions.

**Versions:-**

```
react-native:- 0.61.4,
@react-native-community/netinfo:- 4.6.1
```

Here is my code:-

```
  componentDidMount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
      'connectionChange',
      this.handleConnectivityChange,
    );
  }
  handleConnectivityChange = isConnected => {
    console.log('uyeuiyiuyiu', isConnected);
    this.setState({
      connectionStatus: isConnected,
    });
  };
  componentWillUnmount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener(
      'connectionChange',
      this.handleConnectivityChange,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

you use the new library, but the API you use is Deprecated. you can see this in this [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo).

for android, you have to add the internet permission at the android native `AndroidMainFest.xml`

```
// the app can link the network
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
// get the network state
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
// get the wifi state
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

if you want to know the network is connected, you can use the following code

```
NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
  if(state. isConnected){
   }
});
```

if you want to know when user change the network, whether it is connected, you can use the following code

```
 NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
 if(state. isConnected){
   }
});
```

Comment: @Lenaorod, Thank you for your reply. Where to call this unsubscribe(); function i am using class components not using functional components

Comment: you can call  `NetInfo.addEventListener` directly in the `componentDidMount`

Comment: you can see the library example in ths link(https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo/blob/master/example/IsConnected.tsx)

Comment: I tried this above link but it is also not working for me. I am facing this issue only in android.

Comment: @Harika, did you add the internet permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> ` at the android native `AndroidMainFest.xml`?

Comment: if you want to know the wifi, you also have to add the `<uses-permission
  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission
  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />` permission

Comment: s i already added permission. It is also returning true value while Wifi or mobile data is not connected.

Comment: did you try to use the NetInfo.fetch?

Answer (score 0):

**1- Clean gradlew, run command in your android folder:**

- Linux / MacOS -------------->  ./gradlew clean
- Windows PowerShell --------> .\gradlew clean
- Windows cmd --------------> gradlew clean

**2- Import and use this component:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import NetInfo from '@ react-native-community / netinfo';


class ConnectionInfo extends Component {
    NetInfoSubcription = null;


    constructor (props) {
        super (props);
        this.state = {
            connection_status: false,
            connection_type: null,
            connection_net_reachable: false,
            connection_wifi_enabled: false,
            connection_details: null,
        }

    }

    componentDidMount () {
        this.NetInfoSubscribtion = NetInfo.addEventListener (
            this._handleConnectivityChange,
          );
    }
    
    componentWillUnmount () {
        this.NetInfoSubscribtion && this.NetInfoSubscribtion ();
      }

      _handleConnectivityChange = (state) => {
        this.setState ({
          connection_status: state.isConnected,
          connection_type: state.type,
          connection_net_reachable: state.isInternetReachable,
          connection_wifi_enabled: state.isWifiEnabled,
          connection_details: state.details,
        })
      }

    
    render () {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>
                Connection Status: {this.state.connection_status? 'Connected': 'Disconnected'}
                </Text>
                <Text>
                Connection Type: {this.state.connection_type}
                </Text>
                <Text>
                Internet Reachable: {this.state.connection_net_reachable? 'YES': 'NO'}
                </Text>
                <Text>
                Wifi Enabled: {this.state.connection_wifi_enabled? 'YES': 'NO'}
                </Text>
                <Text>
                Connection Details: {'\ n'}
                {this.state.connection_type == 'wifi'?
                    (this.state.connection_details.isConnectionExpensive? 'Connection Expensive: YES': 'Connection Expensive: NO')
                    + '\ n'
                    + 'ssid:' + this.state.connection_details.ssid
                    + '\ n'
                    + 'bssid:' + this.state.connection_details.bssid
                    + '\ n'
                    + 'strength:' + this.state.connection_details.strength
                    + '\ n'
                    + 'ipAddress:' + this.state.connection_details.ipAddress
                    + '\ n'
                    + 'subnet:' + this.state.connection_details.subnet
                    + '\ n'
                    + 'frequency:' + this.state.connection_details.frequency
                    :
                    this.state.connection_type == 'cellular'?
                    (this.state.connection_details.isConnectionExpensive? 'Connection Expensive: YES': 'Connection Expensive: NO')
                        + '\ n'
                        + 'cellularGeneration:' + this.state.connection_details.cellularGeneration
                        + '\ n'
                        + 'carrier:' + this.state.connection_details.carrier
                    :
                    '---'
                }
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

 
  export default ConnectionInfo;
```

**3- Reconstruct the project from Android Studio from:**

Android Studio> File> Invalidate cache and restart

**4- Put the airplane mode.**

- [Information based on this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=26dk9cLfgfU&t=299s)